# Returning Warnings instead of Errors from Breeze Web API

Tags: c#, error-handling, warnings, breeze

I use Breeze.js and C# WebAPI with BreezeController.  I want to update an entity on the client web page, pass it to the WebAPI for update, save the entity, and send back a warning(s).

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {}
```

Is there a way to return SaveResult with information about a warning?  Not an error, a warning.

Example, I'm saving the age of a resident.  If the age is < than 50 [that is not an error] I still want to warn the user that this may be an incorrect age for a resident based on my business rules.

```
saveResult.Errors.Add(new EntityError() {
                        PropertyName = "Age",
                        ErrorName = "Warning",
                        ErrorMessage = "The age of the resident is less than 50.  You may want to verify that you entered the correct age."
                    });
```

If I do this (This is the behavior I want):

- The entity is correctly saved.
- The Warning message is sent back in the saveResult structure.
- The entity is correctly updated on the server and sent back with the saveResult (i.e. system generated primary key of my entity contains a new ID).

However (This is NOT the behavior I want):

- On the client, the Entity is not updated. i.e the PK is not updated and the Entity is still in a pending state (not saved).

I'm sure that the fact that I return an error in the SaveResult is the problem since Breeze.js is probably interpreting this (correctly) as an error.  However, I don't see how to return the warning using the Breeze model and still have everything functional.

By the way, I know I could be doing that validation on the client side before calling the WebAPI but I want all my validations to be server side, especially since some of these validations are quite complex.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Right now **breeze** doesn't have a concept of 'warnings' as opposed to 'errors' but I do agree that the concept is useful.  Can you add this as a feature request on the breeze User Voice, (http://breezejs.uservoice.com/) and if it gets enough interest we would certainly look into it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've taken the time to add this as a breeze suggestion. Hopefully, this will make it into the next release. In the meantime, any idea how I could implement this?

Comment: I haven't thought about this in detail but you could add an unmapped property called say 'warnings' to each entityType and populate this on the server during the save when an warning occurs.  This would then also be delivered back to the client, and the save would complete normally.

Comment: Great idea, unmapped properties are brought back and mapped by breeze client.  I can then retrieve the warnings.

Comment: Let me know how this works out.  If it works well, we can recommend this to others as well.

Comment: I implemented the warnings by using an unmapped property, implemented on a entity base class, that is inherited by all my entities on the server. On the client, I had to create an Ctor for each entity implementing my message property. Without the Ctor, the unmapped property was being returned by the controller but not "mapped" as a knockout property.  By implemeting a Ctor defining the property, breeze does the mapping automatically. The only thing remaining is then on a successful call to the breeze controller, check if my entities have the warning property and display it.

Comment: Excellent, I'll start recommending this approach if we see the issue again. Thx...